# Interactive model for the PageRank Vector

Tags: matrix, manipulate, graphs-and-networks, recursion, interactive

I'm trying to build an interactive model that will allow me to calculate the PageRank vector of small scale web graphs, however I need the model to also display the graph with the first five most important nodes highlighted and the transition matrix of the same graph with step-by-step computation of the pagerank vector such that the corresponding important 5 vertices show on approximation A<sup>k</sup>v. I understand that I need to use the manipulate function, however don't know how to get it to display and manipulate two things at once.

Any help is appreciated, this is a last resort posting on here, but thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you might want a function like `Grid`, `Row` or `Column` to display several different things in an ordered manner.

Comment: Please provide the code you have to do the individual tasks and we can probably help with placing them in the Manipulate.